# User authentication in socketio

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

In my node project when user logged in, I store user_id in session and socket.id in database with express

```
var httpApp = express();
httpApp.configure(function() {

  req.session.loggedIn = true;
  req.session.userId = row.id;

)};
```

Now, I want to identify user in socket function

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

)};
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest to use this module https://github.com/wcamarao/session.socket.io